# Numero guardado como texto en excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Tengo un automatismo que coge datos de distintos orígenes de datos, el problema es que hay unos datos decimales que me guarda como texto.

¿Como puedo hacer para que no me guarde estos números como texto?

Esto es lo que tengo ahora

```
//Variables interop para excel, xlWorksheet es la hoja de excel.

String excel[100,100]; //Array bidimensional
/*     Mapeo el excel a la matriz     */
       //Aquí habría código

/* Relleno la matriz con datos String */
       //Aquí recogería información


/*     Mapeo la matriz al excel       */ <---- aquí empieza el problema
xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(excel[fila, columna]); <-- esto es String
Range r = (Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[fila, columna];
r.NumberFormat = "#0.00";
```

También he probado con

```
r.NumberFormat = "#0,00";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es cambiar el formato de la celda (o de la columna) en el Excel, haciendo algo como lo siguiente:

Primero, en la celda debes meter el tipo correcto de datos:

```
xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(excel[i, j]);
```

Y después, puedes seleccionar el tipo de formato como en el siguiente código:

```
Range r = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cell[1,1];
r.NumberFormat = "#0.00";
// o para la columna completa
r.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0.00";
```